# MySQL longtext analogue in Microsoft SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am new to Microsoft SQL, and I am attempting to import a database from MySQL. The only issue that I am having is that the MySQL database uses the `longtext` data type for several table columns.

What Microsoft SQL datatype is analogous to MySQL `longtext`?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server has `NTEXT` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)` which are both very similar; `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (or `VARCHAR(MAX)` if you don't need to handle internationalisation) is recommended over the earlier `NTEXT` (and `TEXT` again if you don't need to store anything other than a single codepage.)