# MYSQL to SQL Server UTF8 issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have exported data from mysql to SQL Server but some of the data is displaying as Chinese Symbols in my MSSQL DB. I believe it night be a UTF8 issue.

The field in question is the content field:
In MySql the field is
**Type:** longtext
**Character Set:** utf8
**Collation:** utf8_general_ci

In MsSQL:
**Collation:** SQL_Latin_General_CP1-CI-AS

What can I do to get this data to display correctly in SQL

Comment: you took utf8 and stuffed it into latin-general. your text is corrupted. kill that db, and re-import into a proper utf8 DB in mssql.

Comment: What is the schema of your tables in both databases? And how did you import the data?

Comment: It looks like you should have use an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column in SQL Server for your data: [MySQL longtext analogue in Microsoft SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853839/mysql-longtext-analogue-in-microsoft-sql)